# Lexicographical algorithm enters a closed loop

Tags: combinatorics

I'm writing a Python program that calculates the next Lexicographical Permutation of a list of numbers when I stumbled upon this odd case, the number 113.

Here's how the algorithm works:
https://www.nayuki.io/page/next-lexicographical-permutation-algorithm

So, if you plug in the number 113, and follow the algorithm step by step:

1. Start with 113, the pivot is the middle 1, 1(1)3
2. The rightmost successor to the 1 is the 3 on the right 11(3)
3. You swap the successor with the pivot, the resulting number is 131
4. You reverse the suffix, which also results in 131 (because the suffix is only the 1 on the right)

But, when you repeat the previous steps on the number 131, the resulting number reverts back to 113, even though the next lexicographical permutation should be 311, and we enter a closed loop.

How could I modify the algorithm to fix this issue?

EDIT: Oh, I was wrong. It's my implementation that isn't working properly. Thanks for the answers everybody, sorry to have wasted your time :)

Comment: Must you fix this algorithm or are you looking for an algorithm? If the latter, there may be Python solutions out there. Or sort the list and write a recursive program that starts with a loop on the distinct digits.

Comment: Are you sure about your step 4? It seems to me like the suffix in 131 is 31 (as the longest non-increasing suffix), so the pivot is (1)31, which swaps with 3 for 311 and the algorithm is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow the algorithm with $131$, you do get $311$. Can you show why you think you get something else?

First find the longest nonincreasing suffix, which is $31$. ${1\bf\color{blue}{31}}$.

The pivot is then the leftmost $1$. ${{\bf \color{red}1}\color{blue}{31}}$

The rightmost successor to the pivot is the $3$. ${{\color{red}1}\color{blue}{{\bf3}1}}$

Swap the rightmost successor with the pivot. ${\color{blue}{{3}{\color{red}1}1}}$

Reverse the suffix (meaning reverse the right-most $p$ digits, where $p$ was the length of the original suffix), which here does nothing, since the suffix was $11$.

Result $311$.